# Windows 7 crashes if left idle over night

Tags: windows-7, crash

I have my system working absolutely fine for quite a long time , but in recent times I seem to face the problem of it crashing if left idle for long.

My first step was to initiate safe mode and see if it repeats - It doesn't.

Second step - disable all start up service and programs and check one by one for anything that causes the error to repeat. Result - I avoided unwanted programs and kept what is necessary and it was running fine.

Last night left the system on overnight. It crashed and I cant access the task bar ( I get the wait mouse pointer ). Please see this [Image](https://imgur.com/CTdjU7t)

**My system config:**

```
OPERATING SYSTEM - [ MS windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP-1 ]
CPU              - [Intel Core i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40Ghz ]
MEMORY           - [ 16.0 GB RAM ]
GPU              - [ NVIDIA GeForce GT 530 ]
```

Comment: Have you tested the system with no power saving features operating , just to see if a power profile set to "never never never" changes anything?  The system is rather lame about spinning-down a drive in the middle of a disk operation, as it deems the system to be idle. Also various drivers that might not awaken proper etc.

Comment: When I encoursed a problem like this my hdd was about to fail. A few weeks later it actualled did fail. Windows 7 locking up is an indication that the kernel attempted to do a task that required writting to the disk, was unable to do so, and perhaps even had to unmount the system disk ( although when this actually happen to me it caused a BSOD ) because of a kerbel panic.

Comment: @Psycogeek : my system always is on "never never" power setting

Comment: @Ramhound : thats bad. I am yet to face a BSOD ... I hope nothing happens too bad...

Comment: @abhilashsukumari - You actually are likely getting BSOD crashes because your computer is crashing if its left idle for to long. The problem is you have your computer to automatically reboot instead of creating a memory dump. I just know that when I had a similar problem it was become of my system disk was about to fail. The actuall problem was that the hdd was trying to reallocate sectors continously and wasn't giving back control to Windows.  Post the S.M.A.R.T data on the system disk if you would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe killing explorer.exe through pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and selecting there task manager and then killing the process may help. Then you can restart explorer.exe by selecting at menu bar option **run** and writing `explorer.exe`.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Delete doesn't even show up. That is the problem. I have to FORCE restart every time. The whole system is stuck. I do Ctrl+Alt+Del ,and click on task manager, All I get is black screen.

Comment: Oh, then it's more hard problem. Reinstalling Windows could help, but I don't know if it's any kind of solution for you, if you for example have so important data there.

Comment: Have you tried taking a look into the event log after restarting?

Comment: Description:
A thread in process C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore\mcshield.exe took longer than 90000 ms to complete a request.
 The process will be terminated. Thread id : 6068 (0x17b4)
 Thread address : 0x000000007715138A
 Thread message : 

 Build VSCORE.14.3.0.464 / 5400.1158
 Object being scanned = \Device\HarddiskVolume3\ProgramData\clear.fi\DMR.png
 by C:\Program Files (x86)\Acer\clear.fi Client\ExtractDeviceIcon.exe

Comment: So uninstall McAfee antivirus, its process is causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah thinking of that. But cant even get past the first few start up programs once I restart the PC. So that I can uninstall.

Comment: Try booting off a linux live cd and deleting the program from the c drive

Comment: Gud idea ... That should work it out ...

Comment: @abhilashsukumari Try uninstalling it from safemode first. I think McAfee has a removal tool if you can't remove it from the control panel. Deleting AV files is a good way to quickly hose your system, because they are so tightly integrated into the kernel.